# Computing VMAF Utilizing FFmpeg, Error: Filter libvmaf has an unconnected output

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to gain VMAF for some video sequences in YUV format. When I am trying the below commandline, there is an error saying:

```
Filter libvmaf has an unconnected output
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg -s 3840x2160 -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -i decoded_encoded_h264_55.YUV -s 3840x2160 -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -i S01AirAcrobatic_3840x2160_60fps_10bit_420.yuv -lavfi libvmaf="model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:log_path=VMAF.txt"
```

Any guidance for solving this issue is highly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `ffmpeg` an output. In this case use the [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null):

```
ffmpeg -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 -pixel_format yuv420p10le -i decoded_encoded_h264_55.YUV -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 -pixel_format yuv420p10le -i S01AirAcrobatic_3840x2160_60fps_10bit_420.yuv -lavfi libvmaf="model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:log_path=VMAF.txt" -f null -
```

- I also changed the input options to use the proper [rawvideo options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo).
- See more info and examples in the [libvmaf filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf).